# Why does user location in MKMapView shows latitude 0.0 and longitude 0.0?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, currentlocation

All the questions on stack overflow that are similar to this seem to be for Java and Android.

I have the following code using a MKMapView control.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.followWithHeading, animated: true)

    let locationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    currentLocationCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationCoordinate, latitudinalMeters: 200, longitudinalMeters: 200)

    mapView.setRegion(currentLocationCoordinateRegion, animated: true)

    print("latitude:", mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, "longitude:", mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

}
```

I am using an actual device, so the map view should show my current location and the print statement should print my current location, but instead I see blue on the map view, and the print results show a latitude of 0.0 and a longitude of 0.0 in the debug window:

> latitude: 0.0 longitude: 0.0

Why is it doing this and what should I do to fix this?

I also have a bar button item on a toolbar with the following code:

```
@IBAction func actionShow(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    print("latitude:", mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, "longitude:", mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    let locationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    currentLocationCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationCoordinate, latitudinalMeters: 200, longitudinalMeters: 200)

    mapView.setRegion(currentLocationCoordinateRegion, animated: true)

}
```

That yields the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ask for permission to access user location, this is the first action you perform in `viewDidLoad` and then proceed to show user location once you have the permission, following UIViewController will get you going

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.followWithHeading, animated: true)

        self.checkLocationAuthorization()
    }

    func checkLocationAuthorization(authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? = nil) {
        switch (authorizationStatus ?? CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        case .notDetermined:
            if locationManager == nil {
                locationManager = CLLocationManager()
                locationManager!.delegate = self
            }
            locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        default:
            print("Location Servies: Denied / Restricted")
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 200, longitudinalMeters: 200)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.checkLocationAuthorization(authorizationStatus: status)
    }

}
```

You must also include following properties in `Info.plist`, without these `locationManager` will just not proceed to request authorization.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Message for AlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Message for AlwaysUsageDescription</string>

<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Message for WhenInUseUsageDescription</string>
```